# Vue warn invalid value from option expected an object but got function

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I'm trying to bind a computed function to my style. And in this computed function I'm using a property. But Vue gives me the error that it expects an object but gets a function. This is my code.

```
<template>
  <div id="banner" :style="extractImageURL">

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['imageURL'],
    computed(){
      extractImageURL()
      {
        return "background-image: url(" + this.imageURL + ");"
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It should be `computed: { `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this format:

```
computed:{
  extractImageURL: function()
  {
    return "background-image: url(" + this.imageURL + ");"
  }
}
```

[Vuejs computed guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)